# Multiple Features at the Input Layer Keras Python

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am implementing a simple LSTM network. I would like to include multiple features at the input layer. These features are a pre-trained word embeddings and a vector to flag a specific word in the given sentence.

For example:

```
Sentence = "I have a question"
feature_vector_1 = [4, 2, 281, 5201] #word2index which will be passed to the embedding layer
feature_vector_2 = [0, 1, 0, 0]

final features= [feature_vector_1 + feature_vector_2]
```

suppose that:

```
embedding is of dim = 100
index_flag is of dim = 50 
max sentence length = 50
```

My network code is:

```
input= Input(shape=(None,))
embedded_layer_input=Embedding(input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0], output_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                     input_length=tweet_max_length, weights= [embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input)
lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(64))(embedded_layer_input)
output_layer=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(lstm_layer)

model=Model(input, output_layer)

#complie and train
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])  

# Summarize the model
print(model.summary()) 

# Fit the model
model.fit(padded_train_x, y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, verbose=1, validation_data=(padded_dev_x,y_dev))
```

My question is how and where to include the new feature vector?
I looked at Concatenate but I am not sure how to prepare feature vector 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second input just like the first one and concatenate afterwards:

```
input= Input(shape=(None,))
flag_in = Input(shape=(None,)) ##
embedded_layer_input=Embedding(input_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[0], output_dim=embedding_matrix.shape[1],
                     input_length=tweet_max_length, weights= [embedding_matrix], trainable=False)(input)
combined = Concatenate()([embedded_layer_input, flag_in])
lstm_layer=Bidirectional(LSTM(64))(combined)
output_layer=Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(lstm_layer)
# From now on you pass a list as your input to your model
model=Model([input, flag_in], output_layer)
# ...
model.fit([padded_xtrain, x_flag_inputs], ...)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nuric for your prompt reply. I got an error at the Concatenate line saying:
`ValueError: A 'Concatenate' layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 50, 100), (None, None)]` although I added axis = -1

Comment: I solved the error above by removing the input_length from the embedding layer. But I got another error while fitting the model which is `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (1573, 50)` where 1573 is the number of sentences in the training set and 50 is the number of words in each sentence. The shape of `padded_xtrain` is also (1573,50) so I am not sure what is the problem here?

Comment: You need to `expand_dims` your numpy array of flags. So it is `(1573, 50, 1)` which means every input has 50 words each with 1 feature that you can concatenate. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @nuric. I used `expand_dims(x_flag_inputs, axis=-1)` so the shape of flags is `(1573,50,1)` but I got another error while fitting the model `ValueError: Error when checking input: expected input_2 to have shape (None, 50) but got array with shape (50, 1)`

Comment: my modified code is which gives the above error: `input= Input(shape=(None,))
flag_in = Input(shape=(None,tweet_max_length))
... #as nuric
combined = Concatenate(axis=-1)([embedded_layer_input, flag_in])
...
x_flag_inputs = np.expand_dims(x_flag_inputs, axis=-1)
model.fit([padded_xtrain, x_flag_inputs], y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=False, verbose=1, validation_split=0.1)`

Comment: Oh, you also need to change `flag_in = Input(shape=(None, 1))` so the input has the extra dimension.